# What do epimorphisms in noncommutative rings look like?

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-rings

The question I want to ask is inspired by [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109/what-do-epimorphisms-of-commutative-rings-look-like) mathoverflow post about epimorphisms in the category of commutative rings. I found the seminar (by P. Samuel) referenced by David Rydh particularly interesting so I wanted to ask if anyone could provide me a similar reference for epimorphisms in noncommutative rings.

The reference does not have to be anywhere near as exhaustive as the Samuel seminar is. It can just be a list of interesting examples. In particular, I would be very interested in an example of an epimorphism that is not a combination of surjections and localizations.

If possible, I would really appreciate a reference that is somewhat self-contained. English would also be ideal but if the reference is in French, that would also be ok.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chapter XI of B. Stenström: *Rings of Quotients*, Springer Grundlehren vol. 217, 1975;  [SpringerLink](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-66066-5/page/1); an earlier draft had appeared as LNM 237.

H. H. Storrer: [*Epimorphic Extensions of Non-Commutative Rings*](http://retro.seals.ch/digbib/view?rid=comahe-002:1973:48%3a:11), Comment. Math. Helv. 48 (1973), pp. 72-86.

Related questions and answers:

- [Properties of ring epimorphisms that are true only over commutative rings](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/124462/properties-of-ring-epimorphisms-that-are-true-only-over-commutative-rings)
- [Are epimorphisms from a division ring isomorphisms ?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120918/are-epimorphisms-from-a-division-ring-isomorphisms/121021#121021)
- [Epimorphisms and free submodules](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121468/epimorphisms-and-free-submodules)

Comment: Thank you so much. I like the look of the Storrer reference a lot.